# bbold.sty missing whereas installed with tlmgr

Tags: packages, installing, tlmgr

I installed the [package bbold](https://ctan.org/pkg/bbold) using tlmgr :

```
tlmgr install bbold
```

and it worked fine. However, when I try to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R}$

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `bbold.sty' not found.
```

I do not understand why and how to fix it...

**EDIT 1** The package is present on my computer:

```
$kpsewhich bbold.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbold/bbold.sty
```

**EDIT 2** This is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.10.27)  31 OCT 2023 12:06
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-05>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)

! LaTeX Error: File `bbold.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.3 \begin
          {document}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 229 strings out of 477552
 2815 string characters out of 5827781
 1851759 words of memory out of 5000000
 20836 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 513387 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 35i,0n,38p,141b,36s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: show your log, you probably have two tex systems

Comment: also check the file is there, somewhere like /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbold/bbold.sty

Comment: Ok, I added these two informations to my questions.

Comment: Your log shows that you're running in `/usr/share/texlive`, not in `/usr/local/texlive`, so @DavidCarlisle's assumption is correct, you got two systems installed and are running in one that misses `bbold`.

Comment: To use your  texlive 2023 from tug you updated via tlmgr, you ned to add its bib directory to your PATH if you want to update teh copy in .usr/share update it via your linux package manager, apt or yum or rpm or whatever you use.

Comment: Ok thanks I see the problem now, I will fix it.

Comment: Ideally, install a dummy package to keep your package manager happy so you only have TL under `/usr/local`. Otherwise, you just have to pay attention, I guess.